# svn:mergeinfo on trunk keeps growing

Tags: svn

We have a repository where trunk is branched for each case; work is done in the branch; sometimes the latest changes in trunk are merged (synched) to the branch again; and eventually when all work is done, the branch is merged (reintegrated) to the trunk and the branch is deleted. (In the past we used to have a different work-flow, but we have changed that workflow.)

I have now noticed that the trunk has a property called svn:mergeinfo. If I understand correctly, this property keeps track of all branches that have been 
reintegrated into trunk, just in case we would reintegrate the same branch later again to the trunk so SVN knows what of that branch was already reintegrated.

But I have noticed that svn:mergeinfo on trunk just keeps growing and that entries about deleted branches are not removed from svn:mergeinfo.

I have even done a test where I branched off of trunk, altered one file in one revision, did a full reintegration and deleted the branch. Trunk now has an entry in svn:mergeinfo for the branch I have reintegrated.

I don't know if this is normal behavior or if we're just doing something wrong. Our SVN has lately become a bit slow on switching and merging, and I wonder if this is related. I also don't know if I could or should prune svn:mergeinfo manually.

Comment: That's an artifact of how branching is implemented in Subversion. Note that for a long time Subversion did not record this information and hence there were literally no merge info recored which made reintegrations painful: you had to somehow maintain which revisions of what were merged into what to be able to tell subvesion when merging which is the earliest revision to merge again—to prevent it from re-merging what's already there. Since some time Subversuion learned to record this stuff by itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal, that the property will grow and grow. I would not recommend editing the property manually.

The [SVN book states](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) (bold by me):

> The amount of svn:mergeinfo on a single path **can get quite large**, as can the output of a svn propget --recursive or svn proplist --recursive when dealing with large amounts of subtree mergeinfo. See the section called “Subtree Merges and Subtree Mergeinfo” . The formatted output produced by the --verbose option with either of these subcommands is often very helpful in these cases.

And it also warns about editing the property manually:

> While it is possible to modify svn:mergeinfo just as you might any other versioned property, we strongly discourage doing so unless you really know what you're doing.